# Mathematica can't plot at specific range?

Tags: plotting

**Intentional pseudo-Bug (Thing) introduced in version 1.0 and persisting through 10.3**

---

> I hope that development team fix this issue, will improve in a future release.

I have a function that I need to plot at specific range,but `Plot` dosen't work properly.

A simple example:

```
a = 10^12;
Plot[x, {x, a - 1, a + 1}]
```

Ok work fine.

A next  example:

[image]

For `a=10^14` and `a=10^15` can't see any plot.

For `a=10^16` and `a > 10^16` I see error message.

> Plot::plld: Endpoints for x in {x,a-1,a+1} must have distinct machine-precision numerical values. >>

Comment: What does `1.*^16 - 1 == 1.*^16 + 1` return? Hint: look at the value of `$MachinePrecision`.

Comment: @J.M. Error message that I see.I want to plot a .... `Plot[x,{x,10^20-1/10,10^20+1/10}]`

Comment: @J.M. .How to increase `$MachinePrecision` to `20` or more?

Comment: Then, look up `WorkingPrecision`, and possibly look into tweaking `PlotRange` and `AspectRatio` if you'll be dealing with such extremes.

Comment: It is rather funny that [this thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98366) also came up recently…

Comment: Its not that hard to normalize the function to a practical range then manually specify appropriate ticks.